# php-fpm couldn't find script until I moved in a specific directory

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, http-status-code-404

This morning I had a strange problem about finding php script files with Nginx and Php-fpm.

I solved it, but I didn't understand what the problem actually was.

Some details: I'm on Arch Linux and using PHP-FPM 7.3.9 and Nginx 1.16.1.

I wanted to try the Grav CMS, so I set up nginx and php-fpm as needed. What happened is that php-fpm couldn't find the index.php file, returning a 404 error.

My configuration files are pretty simple: I took the default ones and changed a couple of parameters.

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file is this one

```
user http;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

It's Nginx's default one on Arch Linux where I removed an example server{} block (to include from enabled-sites as in Debian and others) and some comments.

And my configuration file for the specific Grav virtual server was

```
server {
#listen 80;
index index.html index.php;

## Begin - Server Info
root /home/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/grav;
server_name localhost;
## End - Server Info

## Begin - Index
# for subfolders, simply adjust:
# `location /subfolder {`
# and the rewrite to use `/subfolder/index.php`
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
## End - Index

## Begin - Security
# deny all direct access for these folders
location ~* /(\.git|cache|bin|logs|backup|tests)/.*$ { return 403; }
# deny running scripts inside core system folders
location ~* /(system|vendor)/.*\.(txt|xml|md|html|yaml|yml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
# deny running scripts inside user folder
location ~* /user/.*\.(txt|md|yaml|yml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
# deny access to specific files in the root folder
location ~ /(LICENSE\.txt|composer\.lock|composer\.json|nginx\.conf|web\.config|htaccess\.txt|\.htaccess) { return 403; }
## End - Security

## Begin - PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
    # Choose either a socket or TCP/IP address
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; #legacy
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

add_header  x-full-path $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

}
## End - PHP
}
```

As you can notice from the comments, it is the default configuration file provided by Grav itself. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/blob/develop/webserver-configs/nginx.conf).

I just edited the root directory and adjusted the socket path according to my php-fpm one.

I didn't touch any php-fpm configuration.

The result I was getting was "File not found." without any nginx reference. I already encountered that page before, and I knew it was php-fpm's error page.

Indeed, when I changed nginx's configuraton to point at some index.html it worked.

So I tried to check if it was a permission problem (but it seemed weird, I would have expected a different error message): I checked that both nginx and php-fpm were running as the same user (in this case 'http') and I changed the ownership and access mode as myusername:http 775 to give to both my user and http user every permission (I know it's not a good practice, but I was testing).

Still the same error.

I tried also to debug the parameters passed by nginx in the line

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

by commenting that line and adding a header with the value of the parameter.

The path was correct. I copy-pasted it on the terminal to see if there was any typo, but nope. Everything good.

I also tried to pass the absolute path of the index file to php-fpm (in the directive above) but nothing.

At this point I tried one last thing: I moved the 'grav' folder from my dekstop to /srv/http (which on Arch is the default folder in nginx configuration), and edited the nginx configuration files accordingly.
The permissions are http:myusername 664 there.

And it worked.

So I started looking for anything that could've caused the error in php-fpm's configuration files.

I found out the **chdir** option in /etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf .
The comment says

> Chdir to this directory at the start.
>   Note: relative path can be used.
>   Default Value: current directory or / when chroot

Because I did not set chroot (I checked, it's the option above this in the file) it should be /.

But even if it looked for files from root, it makes no sense that it couldn't find the index, because I always passed absolute paths. I couldn't find anything on google about the way fpm intepretes paths according to chdir option.

So, the question is: what happened? Why did it work on one directory and not on another one?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a php-fpm issue, it was a web-server permission issue.
By default on Arch nginx server runs workers as http user, you can see it at the start of your *nginx.conf* file:

```
user http;
worker_processes  1;
```

So the http user couldn't access files in the directory /home/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/grav;

When you moved the files to the directory to which the http user had access, it worked.
You can also change the *user* directive in the *nginx.conf* file and run workers as another user.